# textfield not display the text when i click on table cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

when i click on tableview cell, its not display the text of that cell into textfield .
i have two xib.

1. viewcontroller that contain two field name and salary.and that name and salary insert into sqlite ,all, perform well.
2. next is tableviewcontroller contain table that display sqlite data , when i click on cell its not display in name and slary textfield.

see code ...of tableviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                           didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];

    nameStr =[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    salaryStr=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"salary"];
    NSLog(@"%@",nameStr);//i got the value here
    [vc fillTextfield:nameStr:salaryStr];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)fillTextfield:(NSString*)nm:(NSString*)sal
{

   NSLog(@"string : %@ %@ ",nm,sal);//i also got the perfect value of name and salary here

   //name.text=tblViewController.nameStr;
   // salary.text=tblViewController.salaryStr;

    name.text=nm;
    salary.text=sal;
}
```

but it cant display the text in both textfield....
i also make the outlets and delegate of both textfield .

what can i do here?

Answer (score 0):

you are firstly popping view controller then setting name and salary instead do this:

```
[vc fillTextfield:nameStr:salaryStr];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Also check : if name and salary text field are through xib or programmatically , if through XIB check if you have connected viw iboutlet else put any hard coded value in name.text=@"test name"; salary.text=@"testsal"; also check textcolor property if background and text color are same (thats why it may be invisible)

Thanks,

Comment: First of all thank you dear ....

i change my code as per your advice but its not work ...again same result blank...

Comment: name and salary text field are through xib or programmatically , if through XIB check if you have connected viw iboutlet else put any hard coded value in name.text=@"test name";
    salary.text=@"testsal";  also check textcolor property if background and text color are same (thats why it may be invisible)

Comment: i check all thing ... its proper